# Can't play this video

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When i want to play video from sdcard can't play this video error is shown
the code is
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    vv.setVideoPath("/sdcard/idayam.mp4");
    vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vv.start();
    vv.requestFocus();
}
```

}and my LogCat error is

07-28 16:52:26.874: E/MediaPlayer(23466): error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
vv.setVideoPath("/sdcard/idayam.mp4");
```

to

```
vv.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/idayam.mp4");
```

The path that you are providing is not a valid one. You should always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` to get the path of the SD card

Comment: The same error occurs Can't play this video like that it showed on the screen

Comment: not in logcat In the screen itself the error message is shown

Comment: 07-28 16:46:40.056: E/MediaPlayer(23466): error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: 07-28 16:47:29.644: E/ViewRootImpl(23466): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: You should post all this in your question

Comment: now i edited just have a look at it and please help me to fix this